# Given $N$ find the number of natural numbers less than $N$ that may be written in the form $\frac{(k)(k+1)}{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory

> Given $N$, find the number of natural numbers less than $N$ that may be written in the form $$\frac{k(k+1)}{2},$$ where $k\in \Bbb N$.

I know that the answer to this problem is approximately $\sqrt {2N}$, but I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: What do you mean by "solution"?  A single number, N, does not **have**  a solution.  I suspect you were given some formula, with, say, variable "n", equal to N, but you did not give that formula.

Comment: What do you mean by 'solution'? Also $\sqrt {N}$ doesn't return a whole number unless $N$ is square. Can you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: He probably means the number of natural numbers which can be written in that form, i.e. $n = \left\vert\left\lbrace a\in\mathbb{N}, a<N | \exists k \in \mathbb{N}: a = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}  \right\rbrace \right\vert$

Comment: Edits:the correct answer is "approximately $${\sqrt {2N}}$$ values" and not "$${\sqrt {N}}$$". Sorry i was not able to edit the problem

Comment: also k belongs to the set of Natural numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NOTE: I am counting $0$ as a natural number, so $0$ is one of the solutions since $0=\frac{0(0+1)}{2}$.)

We have the following inequality:
$$\frac{k(k+1)}{2} < N$$

We need to solve for $k$ in terms of $N$. Multiply both sides by $2$ and distribute the $k$ on the left side:
$$k^2+k < 2N$$

Subtract both sides by $2N$:
$$k^2+k-2N < 0$$

Quadratics with positive coefficients are negative in between the zeroes of the polynomial, so we can use the quadratic formula to find the range of possible $k$:
$$\frac{-1-\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot 1\cdot -2N}}{2\cdot 1} < k < \frac{-1+\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot 1\cdot -2N}}{2\cdot 1}$$

First, before we simplify this, notice that $0$ satisfies the original inequality. Therefore, the minimum is less than $0$. However, we only care about natural numbers, so we know that $k > 0$. Therefore, we can get rid of the minimum:
$$k < \frac{-1+\sqrt{1^2-4\cdot 1\cdot -2N}}{2\cdot 1}$$

Now, simplify:
$$k < \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8N}}{2}$$
$$k < -\frac 1 2+\sqrt{\frac 1 4+2N}$$

Now, depending on what $N$ is, this could be $\lfloor \sqrt{2N} \rfloor-1$ or $\lfloor \sqrt{2N} \rfloor$ solutions, but the answer is $\approx \sqrt{2N}$ solutions.